# Why does gcc prefer dynamic library to static one during linking process?

Tags: c, gcc, static-libraries, dynamic-library

I compile and link a simple program:

```
# gcc a.c -pthread
# ldd a.out
        linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffc4ddf2000)
        libpthread.so.0 => /usr/lib/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007fbb75e12000)
        libc.so.6 => /usr/lib/libc.so.6 (0x00007fbb75a6e000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fbb76030000)
```

The program links the shared library. But from [gcc manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-6.3.0/gcc/Link-Options.html#Link-Options):

> -llibrary
>   -l library
>
> ......
>   The linker searches a standard list of directories for the library,
>   which is actually a file named liblibrary.a. The linker then uses this
>   file as if it had been specified precisely by name.
>   ......

It seems the program should link the static library. I find there are both static and dynamic libraries:

```
# ls -alt /usr/lib/libpthread*
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 392576 Mar  6 22:06 /usr/lib/libpthread.a
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     18 Mar  6 22:06 /usr/lib/libpthread.so.0 -> libpthread-2.25.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   1748 Mar  6 22:06 /usr/lib/libpthread_nonshared.a
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 146824 Mar  6 22:06 /usr/lib/libpthread-2.25.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    222 Mar  6 22:06 /usr/lib/libpthread.so
```

Why does `gcc` choose the dynamic one? BTW, is there any difference when using `-lpthread` and `pthread` as the link option during compiling program?

Comment: If you want it to link static libraries, use the `-static` option. The default is dynamic linking.

Comment: That gcc documentation is misleading, please file a bug. You should check your linker's documentation instead (possibly GNU binutils).

Comment: additionally, static linking of archives is always available, so the documentation is just incomplete (not wrong): it fails to mention the fact that on platforms with a dynmic linker, the dynamic shared object is tried first by default.

Comment: Probably a case of un-update manual. AFAIK I know, the recent version of gcc prefers dynamic linking.